# Creating and writing to an UTF-8 file with C++

Tags: file, c++, utf-8

I have to create a m3u8 playlist in my http streaming C++ server code. `m3u8` is nothing but UTF-8 `m3u` file.

How do I create an UTF-8 file (i.e. how to write UTF-8 characters to a file)? Maybe with the `open()` function or some other function in C++ on Linux?

```
int fd = open("myplaylist.m3u8", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
```

Comment: As long as your C++ file is utf8 encoded, it's fine

Comment: yeah i think i have to reframe the question how to write utf-8 characters to a file?

Comment: @neckTwi do you know in advance the contents of the file, or are you getting it from somewhere else?

Comment: @FrederikDeweerdt my code should generate the content of file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you are planning to do the `open()` is fine.

What will determine if a file is in utf-8, is the characters you're going to write to it. Provided you encode the relevant characters as utf-8, everything will work as expected.

If you plan on converting a given encoding (say ISO-8859-1) to utf-8, a good way to achieve it is to use [libiconv](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) which allows to do exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

Whether a file "is" utf-8 depends on the content. As long as you `write()` the correct byte sequences in there you will be fine.